# php: push multiple arrays in one array

Tags: php, arrays

What I am trying to do is to push somme arrays into one array:
The static form of my array is as following:

```
$Data = array
  (
    array('uid' => 1, 'Field Name' => 'xxxx', 'Field Values' => 'xxxx'),
    array('uid' => 2, 'Field Name' => 'xxxx', 'Field Values' => 'xxxx'),
    array('uid' => 3, 'Field Name' => 'xxxx', 'Field Values' => 'xxxx'),
  );
```

I want to obtain the same Data array I tried the next, but it didnt work:

```
   $Data = array();
   // $Columns is an array that contains the Field Names
  for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($Columns); $i++) {
    $newelement=array('uid' =>$i, 'Field Name' => $Columns[$i], 'Field Values' => 'xxxx');
    $Data = array_push($Data,$newelement);
     }
```

Is there a better way than using array_push();  ??

Comment: Why array_push is not good? Also you can use $Data[]=$newlement;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this slightly shorter syntax:

```
$Data[] = $newelement;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Data[] = $newelement
```

$Data[] has the same result as array_push, but mush better perform.

not only shorter syntax, but also more efficiency that there is no overhead of calling a function.

especially, array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array.

This differs from the $[] behaviour where a new array is created.